# how to send string, one char at a time through sock_stream

Tags: c, sockets, serversocket

I am having trouble sending a string, one char at a time through sock_stream connection. The reason for this is that I am attempting to send multiple strings which are nearly 70000 characters at a time. It seems that the write function I was attempting to use requires a string.

```
for(i=0;i<BUF_SIZE;i++)
{
    write(sockfd,plaintext[i],1);
    if(plaintext[i]=='0')
        break;
}
write(sockfd,'^',sizeof(char));
```

Also, how would I read this? Here is how I was attempting it.

```
int read_line(int fd,char message[])
{
    size_t message_len=0;
    while (message_len<BUF_SIZE)
    {
        char c;
        int ret = read(fd, &c, 1);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            message[message_len] = 0;
            return len; // EOF reached
        }
        if (c == '^')
        {
            read(fd,&c,1);
            message[message_len] = 0;
            return message_len; // EOF reached
        }
        data[len++] = c;
    }
}
```

How would I implement this? Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure sending one character at a time is a lot slower than sending them in bulk.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure you're correct, but I have multiple messages being sent which are too large to send in bulk. I could break each message up after a certain number of characters are reached but, for the purpose of this assignment, it seems like that would just cause more potential for errors.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of write api is:
int write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t nbyte);

So what you can do something like:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 70000
char *buf = (char*)malloc(BUF_SIZE);
int written = 0;
int wrote;
if (buf)
   memset(buf, 1, BUF_SIZE);
else
   return written;//some error code

while (written < BUF_SIZE)
{
  wrote = write(fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
  if (wrote < 0)
    return written;
  written += wrote;
}
```

Similarly you should try to do bulk read, as reading one char at a time is too slow unless you have a very valid reason. Each time you do write or read, its system call and they are costly.

So for read you can try something like

int read_bytes = read(fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);

and read_bytes will have the exact value of how much you have read.

Then do parse_buf(buf) in which you can find the tag you are looking for and then save the rest for the future in case you get more data, else if you get less data, then call read again.

Answer (score 0):

You need change line

```
write(sockfd,plaintext[i],1);
```

to

```
write(sockfd,&plaintext[i],1);
```

Additionally, you can use

```
setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *) &flag, sizeof(int));
```

to enable `TCP_NODELAY` option.